# Instagram API python user followed by

Tags: python, api, instagram

Im using "api.user_followed_by" and it only shows 50 users, then shows a link with all the users, like `"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/<id>/followed-by?access_token=<ACCESS-TOKEN>"`
and i need to save in a DB all the users, there's a way to show all the followers of the user? maybe its because im doing this in the shell?

```
([User: victoriasecretmcb, User: laueleizalde, User: marellasdesign, User: caetano_nuno, User: eloy_fernandes, User: sparkles_design, User: xavinavas23, User: kikexr, User: ds_franklin, User: danielcaetano15, User: carlosalicova, User: donmiguelv, User: psteinvorth, User: hakvdub, User: _abrah, User: 7dimitri7, User: j.capote, User: roger_hannouch, User: gguerrero26, User: macmaquillaje02, User: ilgenuas, User: alem274, User: zebrols, User: edwinaleman69, User: gfmmartins, User: dego5, User: eliocastaneda3, User: jeancastilloc, User: dajosama, User: jamesdancer73, User: gavoonmaguire, User: nolygarcia62, User: maajiswim_siut, User: jjuankab, User: tikiticas, User: adefreitasvz, User: tenias66, User: obliviousowl_, User: lykus, User: mc_hasel, User: gabriela_m_oropeza_b, User: gabosanabria, User: adzamski, User: eishynena, User: tropical_chik_ve, User: teddy_bear567, User: cae_ucv, User: nikeexclusivo1, User: pablojmg, User: felixizarra], 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/307622607/followed-by?access_token=307622607.5593d6d.0936a78b99054931982b9b644ec75f48&cursor=1402704073642')
```

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you're using the python library instead of calling this yourself? I've updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use pagination. The API response should include a value called `next_url`, call that an you'll get 50 more users. There's no way to get them all at once without paginating.

See http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

In your case, you appear to be using the Python API Library, so add `as_generator=True` when you call `user_followed_by`. That should return a generator object that you can iterate over.

```
def example():
    generator = api.user-followed_by(as_generator=True, max_pages=None)
    for page in generator:
        print page #page will have the next 50 users, etc
```

Comment: i see, but i dont understand how to use that, can you give me an example?

Comment: Share an API response and I can show you an example

Comment: foll = api.user_followed_by(a), ([User: pablojmg, User: felixizarra], 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/307622607/followed-by?access_token=307622607.5593d6d.0936a78b99054931982b9b644ec75f48&cursor=1402704073642')

Comment: The response, like what is returned to you when you make the call to the API, and put it in the question, will be too big for comment

Comment: sorry, i miss click the enter, i cut the mostly all users to paste the example

Comment: i haven't remove anything, that's what it prints, let me show you in a screenshot

Comment: as you can see it in the screenshot

Comment: a its a instagram ID of an account

Comment: Is the updated answer helping? Are you able to use the generator?

Answer (score 1):

There's an even simpler way to handle pagination in Instagram. This function works for all you're following and you can change it to all you follow. The values of all the users will be in the set of currently_following, a class variable that stores from inside the pagination loop.

```
currently_following = set([])
def parse_following(next_url=None):
    if next_url == None:
        urlUserMedia = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=%s" % (auth_token)
    else:
        urlUserMedia = next_url
    values = {
              'client_id' : client_id}
    try:
        data = urllib.urlencode(values)
        req = urllib2.Request(urlUserMedia,None,headers)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        result = response.read()
        dataObj = json.loads(result)
        next_url = None
        if dataObj.get('pagination') is not None:
            next_url = dataObj.get('pagination').get('next_url')
            currently_following.update(user['id'] for user in dataObj['data'])
        if next_url is not None:
            parse_following(next_url)

    except Exception as e:
        print e
```